# Objective-C: Assigning a value to a static remains nil?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following defined in a header file:

```
static NSArray *knownPrinters = nil;
```

In a test case:

```
knownPrinters = [NSArray new];
```

I have a breakpoint before and after that single line and the value of `knownPrinters` remains `nil` despite being assigned. There is only the main thread and I running only one unit test.

Am I going crazy or is there a legitimate reason why this would occur?

Comment: It's unusual to declare a static variable in a header file. It's usually done in an implementation file. Header files tend to have `extern` globals, not `static` globals.

Comment: I tried extern, got the same thing. I was testing this method because I was having an issue where a @property assigned on a singleton was being free, or otherwise returning to `nil` immediately after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined your global variable by using extern keyword as rmaddy suggested and it is allocated in a unit test under the same conditions you described. Here is the code

```
// Header file

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSArray *knownPrinters;

@interface DummyObject : NSObject

@end
```

Here is the implementation file

```
#import "DummyObject.h"

NSArray *knownPrinters = nil;

@implementation SingletonObject

@end
```

And test file,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "DummyObject.h"

@interface SOStaticAssignTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation SOStaticAssignTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

}

- (void)tearDown {
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testExample {
    knownPrinters = [NSArray new];
    NSLog(@"For debugging");
}
@end
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: You've introduced a class using the singleton pattern, however it's unusual to expose the singleton instance (`knownPrinters` in this case) output of the implementation (`.m`) file.  I don't think the OP is using a singleton pattern anyway; the code could just as easily been C instead of Objective-C.